# Create user session and set cookie with jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, cookies

I am doing a post from my frontend to a backend on another domain to create a session with AJAX.

```
        //create a user session (asynchronously)
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: api_url + "/sessions",
            dataType: 'text'
        })
        .done(function(sessionid) {
            console.log('Sessionid: ', sessionid);
            alert("Session created: " + sessionid);
        });
        return;
```

The server responds with a cookie in the response headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
>   Accept
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
>
> Allow: POST
>
> Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Type:text/plain
>
> Date:Tue, 23 Jun 2015 08:49:11 GMT
>
> Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
>
> set-cookie:myCookie=s%3A6eb8444b-48dd-4084-91aa-3cf14c029b30.c0vbfPAvk6IkAlUE3nGXLEP3p09FDZejokgLyl5KifA;
>   Path=/api; Expires=Sat, 05 Sep 2015 23:12:35 GMT

When I check the resources tab of my browser, I see that this cookie is not being set.
How do I get this cookie to be set?

**UPDATE:**

I added this to the jQuery AJAX request:

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

I can now see that the request is including a Cookie header and that only one session is stored on the server. So it's working as intended.

However, I still do not see the cookie in the resources tab.

Comment: found the correct answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. The cookie is set for /api on another domain. It will therefore not be set as cookie for the page that I am posting from.